# Shopify extension stop during installation

Tags: https, shopify

Hi I'm tring to use an extension in shopify but the installation has stopped in the middle. I've tried in another shop and it's work fine. I can share the issue I have in my dev tool. I don't understand this issue and why it's work for other shops and not for me. I share with you [The errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4feGU.jpg) I have. This  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT9Z6.jpg) is the same one for another shop.

Comment: Contact the App developer and describe the issue to him. At best he will try to install it for you.

Comment: @drip I've developped the extension by myself. the extension works for many shops but I have this issue with two different shops. but I can't understand why it generated if for others no.I've edited the post with a 2nd issue picture.

Comment: This error just says that you are using HTTP url's on a HTTPS site, but I don't think that this should be the actual issue that is preventing the app to be installed.

Comment: @drip, ok because the both issues means the same thing, only one is on  windows and the second one on MAC and the plugin requiered an https protocols. but I don't understand from where the shop is getting the http link. At the first time the access has worked but not the 2nd time.

Comment: any help please?